# How to Delete from a dynamic array

Tags: c++, memory

I am having issues with getting my `MyDynamicArray` class to delete the array. The `delete[] a` statement causes my program to spit out the error "Aborted (core dumped)" when I run it. What could be the problem?

```cpp
private:
    int size, capacity, error, *a;
public:
    MyDynamicArray() {
        capacity = 2;
        size = 0;
        a = new int[capacity]; 
    }
    void del() {
        // half the capacity if the size is 1/4 of capcity
        // make a new array and the free the last one 
        if (size <= (capacity / 4)) {
            capacity = capacity / 2;
            int* a2 = new int[capacity];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                a2[i] = a[i];
            }
            cout << "Reducing to : " << capacity << endl;
            delete [] a;
        }
        size--;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! You seriously need to improve a little bit the formatting (adjust indentation!), You can use ``` ``` and copy paste your code in between

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Please don't change your question I'm a way that invalidates answers. Both answers don't make sense now but were valid before your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/delete-operator-cpp?view=msvc-160)

> Using delete on a pointer to an object not allocated with new gives unpredictable results.

Also you assign value to array a after you try to delete it (your final loop)

Another big problem that I see and may cause the crash is that , in your first loop, you should loop until capacity and not size (assuming that capacity is inferior to size, and you need to implement a check on this to also avoid segfault).

If you want to clear array a of its values, you can use `(void)a;` but it will fill its value with 0.

What you want to do is in fact to fill a2 with value inside of a (that you did), and then change a to point to a2.

Comment: Can you explain _"If you want to clear array a of its values, you can use `(void)a;` but it will fill its value with 0."_ It sounds wrong. That's a C-style cast to `void`. It won't change `a`.

Answer (score 0):

From the given code, I couldn't figure out what you are trying to do. But some issues with the code as given below.

1. You didn't assign any address to 'a' (at least from the given code). You are trying to use it & delete it which will give unexpected results.
2. You are trying to use 'a' after deleting it.